# Minimizing the function with a log determinant and trace function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I am trying to minimize the following argument, which is unbounded in case one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is equal to zero.

$\arg min_{S} \log|S^H A S| - tr\{ \Sigma^{-1}S^HAS\}$

Let $A > 0$, i.e., the eigenvalues of $A$ are always greater than zero. Also, $A$ is full rank and square. $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix. Let the size of $A$ be $n \times n$. Let the size of $S$ be $n \times m$, where $n > m$. Also, rank of $S$ is assumed to be full column rank, which is $m$.

My intuition says that $\hat{S}$, which is the min. value of the above function is formed by taking the smallest $m$ eigenvectors corresponding to the smallest $m$ eigenvalues of $A$. But I don't know how to prove this.

Also, if we assume another constraint on $S$, such that $tr\{ S S^H\} \le p$, where $p$ is a fixed constant, how will this affect the minimization problem?

Comment: My intuition says that the problem might be not convex, as $X\mapsto \log|X|$ is concave.

Comment: That's true. But will adding a constraint help resolve this?

Comment: That isn't convex nor bounded from below for scalars .

Comment: If a constraint such as $tr(SS^H)$ is added, then we may as well write this constraint as $l_2$ norm constraint. Will that help me moving forward?

Comment: Stil, $\log|S^HAS|$ converges to $-\infty$ for $S\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, that is true when $S \rightarrow 0$. But if you have a constraint such as $tr(SS^H) = k$, where $k > 0$, the elements of $S$ have a finite value, and don't tend to zero.

Comment: then the problem has a solution simply due to compactness

Comment: Exactly. But how do I find the solution is my question? Remember, $S$ is a matrix and not a vector.

Comment: Even in the case that $S$ is a vector, the optimum depends on the eigen values of $A$ and $\Sigma$. So your claim is invalid

Comment: I assume eigenvalues of $A$ to be greater than zero and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: You should edit you question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the comments, consider the problem with the additional constraint $tr\{SS^H\} = 1$.

Even in the case of $m=1$, that is $S$ is a vector and $\Sigma$ a scalar, the minimum can be the eigenvector to smallest or largest eigenvalue of $A$ or no eigenvector at all.

In the case of $m=1$, $S^HAS$ ranges exactly over $[\lambda_1, \lambda_n]$, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_n$ is the smallest and largest eigenvalue of $A$.
That is the problem reduces to
$$ \min_{\lambda_1 \le x \le \lambda_n} \log x - \frac1\Sigma x. $$
The optimum is
$$
x^* =
\begin{cases}
  \lambda_n, & \lambda_n \le \Sigma, \\
  \Sigma, & \lambda_1 < \Sigma < \lambda_n, \\
  \lambda_1, & \Sigma \le \lambda_1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a better understanding on how to approach this problem. This is brilliant!

Comment: Can you also provide some references? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean for the range of $S^H A S$? See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem